# Method reference requires API level 22

Tags: java, android, java-8

Based on [Use Java 8 language features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) method references are compatible with **any minSdkVersion**, then why **Method reference requires API level 22**?

Currently, I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1` and JDK 1.8, in *build-gradle* I have:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Example

```
public class SimpleBundleEntry<V> extends BundleEntry<V> {

    public SimpleBundleEntry(String key, V value, 
                            BundleWriter<V> writer, BundleReader<V> reader) 
    {/*init*/}

    // ...

    public interface BundleReader<V> {
        V readValue(Bundle bundle, String key);
    }

    public interface BundleWriter<V> {
        void writeValue(Bundle bundle, String key, V value);
    }
}
```

Problematic code

```
public static BundleEntry<Boolean> ofBoolean(String key, Boolean value) {
    return new SimpleBundleEntry<>(key, value,
            Bundle::putBoolean, // <------------------- PROBLEM HERE
            (bundle, k) -> bundle.getBoolean(k));
}
```

Comment: So which API versions have you installed?

Comment: Maybe the method you are referencing does not exist prior API level 22?

Comment: @RegEdit, I'm using minSdkVersion 16, but lambdas and method references are just syntactic sugar so gradle has to be able to compile them in anonymous classes.

Comment: *gradle has to be able to compile them in anonymous classes*, that's some interesting expectation I must say.

Comment: @Henry I'm invoking Bundle's put{SomeType} methods like boolean, String etc, which are present also in minSdkVersion 16 which I'm using.

Comment: @nullpointer my expectation is based on [Use Java 8 langugage features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

Comment: Please share the code. Provide a complete verifiable minimal example.

Comment: @leonardkraemer code provided.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what method you are calling but there are two different things here.

Android is built on java, which means you have a java version installed on your phone to run the OS.

As java gets updates, some methods are added to the framework and so there are methods that exist in 1.8 that don't on 1.7

But Android is also a platform that get updates, at this time we are the 28th version (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms).

Each one of this version has a new set of methods that dont exist on the previous one.

So if you are calling a method which has been introduced in Android 22 and you are running your application on an API 16 phone, this will lead to a crash.

To prevent this, you'll have to surround the code that requires Android API 22 by

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
   // call the method that needs API 22 at least
} else {
   // do something backward compatible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref : [Lambda expressions](https://barta.me/lambda-expressions-in-android/)

> **Java 8 supported language features**

The Android support of Java 8 language is not complete at the time of writing the post. However, all the **main features are supported and some of them (like lambda expressions) are also backported to API level 23 and lower**.

> Here’s a list of the supported features:

- Lambda expressions (also for API <= 23)
- Method references (also for API <= 23)
- Type annotations (also for API <= 23)
- Default and static interface methods
- Repeatable annotations

Other than the listed, it’s worth mentioning that Stream API is also supported as well as some other features (for a full list, please refer to the official documentation).

Surround the code that Requires API 22 or letter

```
//if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22)
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
  //code...
} else {
   //code.....
}
```

Comment: The `Jack` compiler is dead as a dodo.

Comment: @Sartorius thank you so sorry for that i just copy content miss to edit